# What's the meaning of the ending of "Thirteen Reasons Why"?

Tags: thirteen-reasons-why, jay-asher

Hannah says the words "I'm sorry" and "Thank you" on sides A and B of tape 7.

Why did she say "I'm sorry" and "Thank you"?

Comment: For other people reading this question: The book is _not_ an audiobook. Part of the plot are cassettes that have recordings on them, that's what OP is referring to.